# How to keep the classes with native functions

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

Is it possible to tell the ProGuard to completely skip the class if there is native function in it ?

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { native <methods>; }
```

Above doesn't work for me because it keeps the class names and the native functions names but obfuscates other members

I'd like to know if it's possible to keep everything in such classes without explicitly specifying every class

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to tell the ProGuard to completely skip the class if there is native function in it

Use these rules:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class com.your.packages.** {
    native <methods>;
}
-keepclassmembers class com.your.packages.** {
    native <methods>;
}
```

Note, that "completely skipping" class with Proguard is a always bad idea, because it may also indirectly keep some classes, used from code of your kept classes. Instead I recommend the following mode:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers,allowshrinking,allowoptimization class com.your.packages.** {
    native <methods>;
}
-keepclassmembers class com.your.packages.** {
    native <methods>;
}
```

It will allow shrinking and optimizing code of non-native methods, present in the same class.

You can do even better: if your native methods are resolved by names (e.g. they are called something like `Java_com_your_packages_methodName`), and you don't use `RegisterNatives` to register them explicitly, you may allow shrinking away unused native methods by removing the second rule, which will leave only

```
-keepclasseswithmembers,allowshrinking,allowoptimization class com.your.packages.** {
    native <methods>;
}
```

If you want some of class members to be accessible from JNI (e.g. you have some static callback methods to be called from native code), you should keep them *explicitly*: annotate each such member with specialized annotation and use an annotation-based rule to keep them:

```
-keepclassmembers,allowoptimization,includedescriptorclasses class com.your.packages.** {
    @android.support.annotation.Keep *;
}
```

You can use your own annotation in place of the one from Android support library — in fact, it is better to use your own in order to avoid interference from existing consumer rules, coming from Android Gradle plugin or other libraries.

---

In general, I recommend you to reduce the amount of friction between JNI and Java code as much as possible. If you have multiple related Java methods, called from JNI, try to put them together in the same method:

```
@Keep
public static void callback(int action, String arg) {
    switch (action) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Throw your exceptions from Java code (you was going to reflectively invoke their constructors anyway, so may as well invoke a static helper method instead):

```
@Keep
public static void throwException(int type, String message) {
    switch (type) {
        case 0:
            throw new BadThingsHappenedException(message);
        case 1:
            throw new AllHopeIsLostError();
        ...
    }
}
```

If you have a class, that has to be passed to JNI, try to pass individual fields instead of that class:

```
public final class DataClass {
    int intField;
    String stringField;

    public void doSomeNativeOperation() {
        JNI.doSomeNativeOperation(this);
    }
}

public final class JNI {
    public static void doSomeNativeOperation(DataClass arg) {
        doSomeNativeOperation0(arg.intField, arg.stringField);
    }

    private static native void doSomeNativeOperation0(int intField, String stringField);
}
```

If you have a native peer class (a class, closely connected to some structure in native memory), you can keep a pointer to native structure in that class in `long` field, and pass that field to native methods. Then in native methods cast that `long` to pointer:

```
public final class Peer {
    long pointer;

    // constructor is invoked from JNI
    @Keep
    protected Peer(long pointer) {
        this.pointer = pointer;
    }

    public void doSomeNativeOperation() {
        JNI.doSomeNativeOperation(this);
    }
}

public final class JNI {
    public static void doSomeNativeOperation(Peer peer) {
        doSomeNativeOperation0(peer.pointer);
    }

    private static native void doSomeNativeOperation0(long pointer);
}
```

And in native code:

```
void JNIEXPORT Java_com_your_packages_methodName(JNIEnv* env, jobject type, jlong ptr) {
    struct my_struct peer = (struct my_struc*) (intptr_t) ptr;
    ...
}
```

These simple rules will allow you to fully obfuscate any huge application using JNI, except for a single small class, that contains all `native` methods.

I suggest you go even further and push for repackaging classes, referenced by native callbacks.

Instead of

```
@Keep
public static void callback(YourCustomType arg) {
    ...
}
```

You can omit a type of parameter by replacing it with `Object`:

```
@Keep
public static void callback(Object arg) {
    // this cast won't make much difference in performance, but it makes huge
    // difference for Proguard!
    YourCustomType instance = (YourCustomType) arg;

    ...
}
```

This will let you obfuscate and repackage even types of callback arguments.

Comment: nice explanation there, I trust you have also tried to approach it in terms of security with regards to reverse engineering; ways to make it more difficult

Comment: If I use `@Keep` annotation, won't it be easy for an **attacker** to look for the `@Keep` annotation entries in my source code in attempt to identify specific methods called from JNI? If so, is it better to `-keep` the methods by referencing them directly from proguard file?

Answer (score 1):

Use -keep instead of -keepclasseswithmembernames

```
-keep class * { native <methods>; }
```

For more info: https://jebware.com/blog/?p=418

> -keep disables all of ProGuard’s goodness.  No shrinking, no obfuscation; not for classes, not for members.

Comment: I tried this but it will "keep" all classes in the app

Comment: not if you qualify it with { native <methods>; }   then only classes with native methods will be kept

Comment: Ok, I'll double check it